# Display SQL database query result as link

Tags: php, sql, html

I have a search form on a previous page where I allow users to search for $q. I then query the database for 'keys' LIKE  $q.  The while loop displays the 'name' and 'weblink' of each matching database entry.

This all works correctly. However, I would like the 'weblink' to display as a clickable link. Ideally it would read as if it were HTML: 'weblink'. I cannot figure out the correct combo of php and html to make both the while loop, and the HTML work.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
// query database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `forumlist` WHERE  `keys` LIKE  '%$q%'");
// display query results
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $row['weblink'];                           
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo '<a href="' . $row['weblink'] . '">' . $row['weblink'] . '</a>';                           
    }
```

Comment: @SeanA Why would I want to do that?

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @alex Oops, yeah, you are right.  I just meant if `weblink` happened to have a double quote in it, it would break the HTML, so you may need to handle that, especially if `weblink` is user input.

Comment: @SeanA If it were user input, I would echo with `htmlspecialchars()`.